# Обработка нажатий в canvas

Tags: javascript

```
 <canvas id='example'>Обновите браузер</canvas>
        <script>
            var example = document.getElementById("example"),
                ctx     = example.getContext('2d');
            example.width  = 640;
            example.height = 480;
             ctx.fillRect(25,25,100,100);

        </script>
```

У меня есть вод такой код который рисует в канвасе квадрат. Могу ли я обработать событие - нажатие на этот квадрат. Т.е. к примеру дать этому квадрату id1 и при нажатии перейти на page?id=1 ?

Comment: Нет, не можете.

Comment: А что лучше использовать для такой цели? svg?

Comment: Можно тупо по координатам этого прямоугольника, можно прямоугольник производить методами Path2D и тогда можно отследить isPointInPath, короче можно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил две фигуры методами `Path2D()`. Каждой фигуре задал `id`. При клике по `canvas` смотрю попало ли нажатие на какую-нибудь фигуру и получаю `id` этой фигуры. Обработчик можно дальше ставить любой.

Конечно, и фигуры можно добавлять более программно. Можно картой фрагментов (подготовить все пути в векторном редакторе), заносить эти пути в json, например и давать им осознанные атрибуты.

```js
var example = document.getElementById("example"),
ctx = example.getContext('2d');
example.width  = 640;
example.height = 480;

let rectangle1 = new Path2D();
rectangle1.rect(25,25,100,100);
rectangle1.id = 1;
ctx.fill(rectangle1);

let rectangle2 = new Path2D();
rectangle2.rect(150,25,100,100);
rectangle2.id = 2;
ctx.fill(rectangle2);

let figures = [rectangle1, rectangle2];

example.onclick = e => {
  figures.forEach(f => {
    if(ctx.isPointInPath(f, e.offsetX, e.offsetY)){
      console.log(f.id);
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<canvas id='example'>Обновите браузер</canvas>
```

Comment: Хотя с svg можно проще, конечно. И атрибуты сразу в XML забивать))